# Сортировка ответа связанных таблиц mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

при запросе к базе и установки связи - все время возвращается перемешанный ответ.

```
SELECT users.*, 
       roles.name AS role_name, 
       divisions.name AS div_name 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN divisions ON users.divisions_id = divisions.id 
LEFT JOIN roles ON users.roles_id = roles.id 
ORDER BY role_name desc
```

И ответ каждый раз перемешивает строки.
А вот так ответ всегда постоянный:

```
SELECT users.*, 
      ( SELECT name 
        FROM divisions 
        WHERE divisions.id = users.divisions_id
        ) AS div_name, 
      ( SELECT name 
        FROM roles 
        WHERE roles.id = users.roles_id
        ) AS role_name 
FROM users 
ORDER BY role_name DESC
```

Я так понял это проблема в объединение.

`straight_join`  не помог или я не правильно понял.

Comment: А, пардон, `role_name` в получаемом результате выполнения запроса часом не дублируется? если да - то тебе просто не хватает критериев сортировки для этих дубликатов. Расширь выражение ORDER BY - оно должно обеспечивать уникальность результирующих записей. *А вот так ответ всегда постоянный* - это до поры до времени...

Comment: Да, все верно, дублируется. Когда добавляю в ORDER BY еще поле уникальное - работает все хорошо

Comment: `straight join` отношения тут не имеет, он нужен для явного указания порядка соединения таблиц. Ибо в запросах вида from a join b, планировщик в зависимости от размера таблиц например может сначала читать таблицу а и потом джойнить b, а может вполне и наоборот сделать, а если к этому добавится сортировка по полю таблицы из from, например, то разница может быть весьма велика, в одном случае возможно будет использован индекс при наличии, во втором - придется все пихать во временную таблицу, а если например там text поле есть, то это будет таблица на диске, а не в памяти.

Comment: В общем иногда, можно, явно указать порядок чтения таблиц, исходя из анализа плана выполнения запроса. к порядку сортировки записей это отношения не имеет

Comment: спасибо! за совет